# Including Modules in Ruby

Tags: ruby, module, include, ruby-1.9

I am trying to include a Ruby module.

In the file helper.rb, I have this text

```
module Helper
...
end
```

In the file test.rb, I have this text:

```
....
require 'helper'
...
```

These files are on the same level of the directory yet I keep getting this error:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- helper (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from test.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

I have also tried

```
include Helper
```

in test.rb and get this error:

```
test.rb:4:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Object::Helper (NameError)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9 you should use

```
require_relative 'helper'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `require './helper'`. That should do it.